# Debugging killed app in xcode debugger(Notification Debugging)

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, notifications

My notifications is crashing the IOS App when the user clicks the notification after the app was killed and removed from the background/foreground.  I don't know how to get debugging information if the app isnt being ran.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to edit your scheme, choose `Run` on the left bar. and `Info` on the top tab bar.

Change `Launch` to `wait for executable to be launched`.

Now, you can run the app. the app will not launch and therefore, will not crash.
get the notification, open it, and debug the crash.

[image: Edit scheme window]