# How to enable debug mode after killing the app

Tags: xcode, debugging

How to enable debug mode after kill app and relaunch it again?
What are the steps to get debug-mode enable?

Comment: Maybe your answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59896343/debugging-killed-app-in-xcode-debuggernotification-debugging

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot debug the app after killing app from simulator as when we kill the app it stops the app process and debugging session. so, the breakpoints which are use for debugging purpose of app are no longer active so, we cannot enable debug mode after killing the app.